# How to limit subnodes from each nodes Neo4j Cypher

Tags: cypher, neo4jphp, node-neo4j, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j,I have the following situation

[image]

In the above diagram represented a node with label `user` with sub-nodes having label `shops`. Each of these sub-nodes have sub-nodes with label `items`. Each node `items` has attribute `size` and the items node is in descending order by `size` attribute for each  node `shops` as represented in the figure.

### Question

I want to get two `items` node whose size is less than or equal to `17` from each `shops` .
How to do that? I tried, but its not working the way I need

Here is what I have tried

```
match (a:user{id:20000})-[:follows]-(b:shops)
with b
match (b)-[:next*]->(c:items)
where c.size<=17
return b
limit 2
```

**Note-** These `shops` node can have thousands of `items` nodes. So how to find the desired nodes without traversing all thousands of `items` nodes. 
Please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: are those size attribs of int type or is it stored in string form in the node attrib?

Comment: size attributes are of int type

Answer (score 3):

Right now Cypher does not handle this case well enough, I would probably do a java based unmanaged extension for this.

It would look like this:

```
public List<Node> findItems(Node shop, int size, int count) {
   List<Node> results=new ArrayList<>(count);
   Node item = shop.getSingleRelationship(OUTGOING, "next").getEndNode();
   while (item.getProperty("size") > size && results.size() < count) {
       if (item.getProperty("size") <= size) result.add(item);
       item = item.getSingleRelationship(OUTGOING, "next").getEndNode();
   }
   return result;
}


List<Node> results=new ArrayList<>(count*10);
for (Relationship rel = user.getRelationships(OUTGOING,"follows")) {
   Node shop = rel.getEndNode();
   results.addAll(findItems(shop,size,count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to traverse all items of each shop by grouping them according to size.  In this approach, your graph looks like this

```
(:User)-[:follows]-(:Shop)-[:sells]-(:Category {size: 17})-[:next]-(:Item)
```

You could then find two items per shop using

```
match (a:User {id: 20000})-[:follows]-(s:Shop)-[:sells]-(c:Category)
where c.size <= 17
with *
match p = (c)-[:next*0..2]-()
with s, collect(tail(nodes(p))) AS allCatItems
return s, reduce(shopItems=allCatItems[..0], catItems in allCatItems | shopItems + catItems)[..2]
```

`shopItems=allCatItems[..0]` is a workaround for a type checking problem, this essentially initializes shopItems to be an empty Collection of nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is not what I wanted. Please read my question

Comment: What part of your question did I not understand? I think it is not possible to efficiently execute your query as you will always have to scan all shop items until you find the ones that have the correct size (as suggested by @MichaelHunger). Hence I suggested this solution based on a modified data model.

Comment: If you wanted to be truer to your original model, you could instead use a sorted, linked list of categories where each category also holds its items.  Still, any generally efficient solution will have to separate items from categories.